# Creating link between geopackage and pdf

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, hyperlink, actions

I'm trying to create a link between geopackage and a folder that contains pdf files. There are points with the same name and they should open the same pdf. I want name 100 to open 100.pdf. Name 101 should open 101.pdf

[image: Picture of attribute table geopackage]

My folder looks like picture 2.[image: The folder]

In QGIS 3 I've been trying to create this link under "actions" but don't understand how to connect this. Is it possible?

[image: Action]

Answer (score 1):

Action Type Open, Action Text like :
`[% "full_path_to_your_file" %]`
should work ...
You don't need (i think) to mention any path to an explorer executable ...

After **Techie_GUS** comment *(sorry ... i read the question too quick)* :

```
c:\your_path\[%Namm%].pdf
```

Should work (works for me in any case).

Comment: The open action will open the file with its associated application, provided it's installed. What the OP wants is to define the path to the file dynamically. He has the filename without the extension in the table. So he needs to attach ".pdf" to the field value and feed it to the open action.

Comment: The above line doesn't work for you ?